# Feasibility of MMO 3D game on HTML5/WebGL

Tags: javascript, html, opengl-es, webgl

I don't know if anyone thought about this but are games like World of Warcraft, Lineage II, or Aion, feasible with a browser front-end through WebGL? What are the things I would have to consider if I want to make a full fledged game with these new technologies? Also, what would be a good place to start?

Comment: This seems like a good question for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 4):

This may be too open-ended, but I will take a stab.

First, there is no modeling programs that will output what you expect, as far as I know, since you will need javascript outputted.

Some browsers will use the hardware to accelerate the graphics, but that isn't a guarantee, and your only getting a bit of the cpu, sharing with the other tabs, so it may not be as smooth as you like.

If you have to download a large amount of data to run your program that will be a problem for the user.

I think the modeling program is the real challenge though, as you will have to basically do everything by hand, and the fact that it won't be very smooth will be an issue, unless you design for this.

But, for some game designs WebGL should be a fantastic choice.

Comment: If you can find a way to minimize the cost of transporting massive amounts (possibly gigs) of resources, having the game running in the browser should work alright. The support files that come with games tend to be the killer here, though. Be a great system if it was easily possible, and WebGL is definitely something that will be fun to play with.

Comment: @peachykeen - WebGL is a fantastic technology, but coming up with a game that works well with it will require creativity.

Comment: Well, HTML5 supports caching, but I don't think it's on the scale of the gigs necessary to run a huge MMO.  Great for smaller games though!!

Answer (score 3):

In fact it is fully possible, and we will se such games.

We can expect libraries like O3D to take care of the browser quirks. We already have these problems on desktop platforms and libraries takes care of multi-platform portability there.

Browser cache can be a slight problem, but not a big one. It is possible to assign more cache to games, and we also have proxy servers like squid that can cache very large resources. If a group of players on a LAN share a proxy server they will also share large resource objects, if the game are well designed (ie the resource cannot have multiple generated names, but be have a common URL for all players.)

Also there are discussions about adding local storage possibilities for web applications.
And "ready to be hacked" is not a mayor issue. There are nothing to stop hackers from manipulating Flash or C++ applications, anti-cheating tools are already rendered useless. Blizzard is already relying on spotting "bot-like behavour" rather then try more anti-hacking measures.

However, I do not think that WoW will be the first flash-based games. In fact it will be Quake (http://playwebgl.com/games/quake-2-webgl/) as there is already a Quake-port for WebGL... There will be web games that makes use of WebGL, but do not count on Blizzard supporting it in the near future.

IE is the only browser that does not support WebGL and to be honest that does not matter. All other browsers do, and users will not mind running Chrome or Firefox. Or running both and choose the one that is faster for their game.

Who cares of marginalized browsers like IE and Opera. They are equally unimportant. Unless you count IE6 which will never support any of the stuff we are discussing, as it is discontinued and unsupported.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it's possible if your game must go beyond some cubes on heigtmaps.

- Large amounts of coding in JS multiplied by browsers quirks. (Yes, I'm aware of JQuery, but it's not panacea)
- Large resources hanging on tiny thread of browser cache
- Ready-to-be-hacked client code exposed to a lot of browser tools like Firebug

Such game is much more realistic on Flash, especially with upcoming 11 version of player with hardware 3D.

Comment: The browsers that currently support WebGL are few, and so the browser quirks are less of an issue. Should IE ever support it then this becomes a bigger issue.

Comment: Uh, Chrome, FF 4 and Safari all support WebGL. Those are the big players in my book.  Basically, the only one that doesn't is IE...

Comment: @tjameson - Last I saw to get Chrome to use WebGL was more than just running the program, I would have to pass a parameter to use (so I used Chromium for testing).  I didn't realize Safari is using WebGL though, that is good.

Comment: Yeah, webgl works out of the box on chrome. I think this changed with either version 9 or 10

Answer (score 1):

For caching local files, you should look into the File System APIs that are now in Chrome.  This gives you programmatic access to a virtual file system, letting you control what resources you store locally.

The Application Cache can help you with static resources like the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript required for the game.  However, you need to run as an "installed web app" (via the Chrome Web Store, for example) to get unlimited storage.  Browsers are building quota management systems to help make this easier.

WebGL is great, and the libraries are emerging to help make it easier.  There's no clear "winner" but lots of options.

JavaScript is pretty fast these days, thanks to improvements like CrankShaft.  For even better performance, you can use Native Client to run your C/C++ code and post messages back and forth to JavaScript.

There are two big issues that I can see.  One is helping the middleware companies port their work to JavaScript or Native Client.  The second is improving the speed with which we can move data from JavaScript into WebGL.

Answer (score 1):

Runescape one of the most played browser games for many years is rewriting their engine in with WebGL... (They currently use Java applets)

Answer (score -1):

"If you can find a way to minimize the cost of transporting massive amounts (possibly gigs) of resources"
Actually http already has the minimal cost of transporting gigs of static resources. With its native resource allocation scheme, the URL, it has the ultimate caching abilities. Not only does browsers know how to cache static resources by URL, but fast and efficient proxy servers exists that can handle terrabyte of data.

The main secret to this is the HTTP HEAD requeset, where the browser of proxy server efficiently can check if it has the latest version of the resource and re-syncronize it. Also it is possible trough HTTP headers to mark a resource as eternal or very long-living (immutable). re-syncronization will then be impossible, instead updates will be done by creating a new resource with a new name.

There is a myth that HTTP is somehow inefficient as a resource transport system, when in fact it have been designed to be very efficient.

WoW and other clients that use proprietary protocol are notoriously inefficient compared to HTTP-based clients. These client cannot be accelerated using proxy servers. Windows update, Apt and Yum all have in common that they update OS resources with HTTP and have been able to leverage Akamai:s vast global networks of proxy servers among other similar resources in order to efficiently transfer URL resources in the scale of many gigabytes per client.